# Add navigation menu in custom lightning app (LEX look and feel)

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

When I switch to LEX, `one/one.app` opens and it has a beautiful left navigation menu and a header as well. From Account detail page, on click of a button I need to open a different lightning app i.e

> /namespace/AccountModificationRequestApp.app

Now this is working fine but the AccountModificationRequestApp.app doesn't have the lightning look and feel since its missing the navigation menu & header.

Is there any way to include them in custom lightning app?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a direct link, you need to fire an force:navigateToComponent event: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToComponent.htm

Alternatively, if your component is not too big, you can call it directly from a button but it will appear in a modal:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1_config_action.htm

You won't be able to use a .app directly, but you can create a component with the exact same content in it and it will work.

Comment: Thanks Fabien. For `force:navigateToComponent` to work, I need a JS console, since OnClick JS buttons are not supported in LEX, opening a Vf and then firing `force:navigateToComponent` is my option. Will `force:navigateToComponent` work in script tag of Vf?

Comment: Nope! In VF `$A` is not defined even if I add `<apex:includeLightning/>`

Comment: Currently I don't think there is any way to open a component in "full screen" with header and sidebar using the standard buttons. Either you create a button in a component that you'll display on the page using App Builder (not great because it will not be at the same place than the other standard buttons), or you create an empty component for a custom action. Then you can call force:navigateToComponent from the init handler. Not that nice because for a second you'll see the modal before being redirected.